# How do I make something happen only on explicit user change and not a model change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a input field whose model is binded to an object's property in JSON. Now the ng-change on this model triggers even if the value is changed internally by code or API. However, I have a requirement wherein the method on ng-change should execute only when user types something in input box.

How can I achieve the above functionality. Using watch provides the same results. I am confused if it is feasible at all using AngularJS

Comment: how about `ng-keyup` ??

Comment: I tried using ng-keyup and down..facing latency issues with them

Comment: Do you have some example code? In my tests ng-change is only being called when the user changes the input, not when changed by code. This is with version 1.4.7.

Comment: I think your making some other mistake while its clearly stated in angularjs docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) that ngChange fires only on when input is changed by user.Here is plnkr demonstrating it : http://plnkr.co/edit/O2l544KgWMRIwEqyYW3L?p=preview